# Stuck with strip_tags why not working in my code?

Tags: php, html, string, strip-tags

I want to remove quotes and html tags from following string:

```
$mystring='Example string "I want to remove any html tags ABC<sub>DE</sub> from <p>similar</p> types of string?"';
```

I am using following scripts to remove it but it's doesn't work for me:

```
echo strip_tags(htmlentities($mystring,ENT_QUOTES));
```

I want to following output for above string:

```
Example string "I want to remove any html tags ABCDE from similar types of string?"
```

Why strip is not working?What I mess here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first use **strip_tags** function if you want remove html tags then use **htmlentities** as follow it should be work:

```
echo htmlentities(strip_tags($mystring),ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: I have to escape single or double quotes along with striping tags from the strings. that scripts works fine .thanks

Answer (score 7):

Once you use `htmlentities()` on that string there are no tags left to strip because they have been converted, well, to their HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this code

```
echo strip_tags($mystring);
```